# What causes javascript error "Expected identifier and instead saw else"?

Tags: javascript

Error message:

```
"Expected identifier and instead saw else."
```

Here's the code (All Javascript) :

```
// Write your function below.
// Don't forget to call your function!
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
    if (numHours >= 8); {
        console.log("You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!");    }
    else {
        console.log("Get some more shut eye!");
    }
};
console.log(sleepCheck)
```

Comment: You have a semicolon in `if (numHours >= 8);` which is incorrect. You should also put in the effort to format your code if you expect people to read it and help you.

Comment: Maybe get some more sleep and the answer will be obvious..

Comment: I recommend making your function like so:                         `function sleepCheck(numHours){ ... }` Then for calling: `sleepCheck(someNumberHere);`. This is much more common and correct.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't have a semicolon here:

```
if (numHours >= 8); {
```

an `if` statement structure should look like this:

```
if (condition) {

} else if (condtion2) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a semicolon after the closing parenthesis of the `if` statement.